# "in" or "for"? -- "They grow over 20% yearly ____ (the) past five years"

Tags: grammar

> 1. They grow over 20% yearly in the past five years.
> 2. They grow over 20% yearly for past five years

Which of them is more appropriate? Or are they both not correct?

Comment: Neither are correct. What you probably want to say would normally be expressed as *"They have grown by over 20% per annnum (or "annually") for the past five years"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most appropriate version would be 
`"They have grown by over 20% per annum for the past 5 years."`
`"for"` would indicate that the said event occurred every year through the entire span.
`"in"` is usually used to indicate an event that occurred once in those 5 years.
For example,

> "Business has grown a lot **in** the past 5 years" *as against* 
>   "I have been watching over this area **for** the past 5 years."

Comment: Most welcome. If this answers your question, you can select it as the answer.

Comment: and may i know the use of for and in here, what is the difference?

Comment: I disagree that the "per annum" is the "most appropriate version." Shame the O.P. was convinced to select this as "the answer" without giving ample time for others to respond; I strongly recommend waiting **at least** half a day, if not a full day, before selecting an answer.

Comment: @J.R. - Mind sharing the appropriate version with that bout of criticism? _Why_ is "per annum" not appropriate enough? And why this heavy a criticism? If you don't agree with my answer, you could always comment in suggestions. Some Constructive criticism here?

Comment: I only mildly disagree with the answer, but the heavy-handed, "If this answers your question, you can select it as the answer" – literally minutes after the question was posted, to a brand new user – rubbed me the wrong way. I often exhort users to wait awhile before picking an answer. As for what is wrong with "per annum" – it may work for a formal report, but it doesn't strike me as being for very good for day-to-day, conversational English – certainly not "most appropriate." There's more to the conversation than you've provided here, and the O.P. has the right to be informed of that.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for doing that. And By the sound of the sentence, I felt it was something that'd go in a formal report of sorts. Hence I suggested per annum.

Answer (score 2):

Ditto @ashish. Or you could say, "They grew by 20% per year for the first five years." And no doubt many other variations.

But I think the real point of your question was to ask about "for" versus "in".

If you say that something happened "for the last five years", that means it happened every year in that range, or it was happening repeatedly or continuously over that time. If you say that something happened "in the last five years", you usually mean that it happened at least once in that time. Example:

"Which employees worked in London in the last five years?" This is asking for a list of employees who, at some time within those five years, worked in London. If an employee was in London just briefly for one year, we'd expect him to be included in the list.

But, "Which employees have been working in London for the last five years?" This is asking for people who have been in London continuously for that period. Someone might question if an employee who had been in London for 4 1/2 of those years and briefly working somewhere else should be included, but the thrust of the question is for people who have been there the whole time. An employee who had been in London for six months of one year would not be expected to be included.

Comment: +1 for suggesting _grew_, plus all the other good advice in this answer.